Flyout layout behavior in .NET MAUI
I can't find the FlyoutLayoutBehavior in the flyoutPage tag.
I can't see this property at all.
it's like I don't have this property in the list and I don't know what to do. please someone?
Maybe I should update something?

You can try to update your visual studio to the latest version and try again.
